# what are some Applications usecases that scale on application level metrics?

Tags: performance, kubernetes, cloud, scaling, metrics

Can someone tell me use cases that uses custom metrics to scale and the reason for using that?

i have heard some application uses custom application metrics to scale, why cant we just use cpu metrics ?

Comment: Have you seen this article by any chance? https://towardsdatascience.com/kubernetes-hpa-with-custom-metrics-from-prometheus-9ffc201991e

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you also would like to scale based on external factors, for instance:

- scale based on the number of messages in a queue
- scale based on the incoming traffic in another service

so you can predict an increase in your traffic and be preventive instead of reactive to the load.

Also no long time ago the scale based on memory consumption was not accurate so this used to be another use case.